# Type of adsorption in catalysis

Tags: physical-chemistry, catalysis, adsorption

why type of adsorption takes place during catalysis? It can't be physisorption because it involves formation of chemical bond. It shouldn't be chemisorption too because it is characterised by desorption, where as desorption takes place in chemisorption. So basically what kind of adsorption is involved in catalysis?

Comment: What type of catalysis?

Comment: @DGS            In general, i.e. both hetero and homogeneous catalysis.

Comment: But like transition metal catalysis? There are just so many ways catalysis can occur. Oh, I just saw. Heterogeneous catalysis is mentioned on the [chemisorption Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemisorption). However, I don't think homogeneous catalysis works through adsorption.

Comment: @DGS            Yeah sure but, chemisorption do not involve desorption but in heterogenous catalysis desorption takes,place.

Comment: What do you mean "chemisorption does not involve desorption"? I think this is may be a misunderstanding. You can have hydrogen adding and eliminating from a platinum surface, but because the H-H bond breaks and the Pt-H bond forms, it is chemisorption, even though the reaction is in equilibrium. It is still a chemical reaction and chemical change.

Comment: @DGS             Yeah, that was my misunderstanding, thank you , should I delete this question?

Comment: Nope. Someone might have the same question some day. You could always provide a formal answer yourself and probably get some additional reputation in the process.